# unable to dequeue a cell with identifiermust register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to add endless scrolling to my iOS app and I'm hitting a snag.

I created a Loading cell for showing a spinner when the data is being fetched, I then assign it like so in my TableView Source object:

```cs
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if (indexPath.Row == _comments.Items.Count && !_comments.IsLastPage)
    {
        var loadingCell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(LoadingIndicatorCell.Key, indexPath) as LoadingIndicatorCell;

        loadingCell.Update(UIColor.Black, true);

        OnLoadNextPage?.Invoke(tableView, null);

        return loadingCell;
    }

    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CommentCell.Key, indexPath) as CommentCell;

    cell.Update(_comments.Items.ElementAtOrDefault(indexPath.Row), tableView);

    return cell;
}
```

when I scrolled to the bottom I get the following message:

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: unable to dequeue a cell with identifier LoadingIndicatorCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

I'm following [this](https://github.com/b099l3/LoadingTableExample) example as it's the only reference piece I found that matched what I wanted to achieve.

I simply just want a way to show a spinner once the user gets to the end of the view and then load more data, I figured it out on Android but iOS is giving me the most headaches on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have to register the loading nib, adding that fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to mark your answer, it will help others who have simialr issue.

Comment: SO doesn't let me do that until after 2 days